# Capture normal (stdout) output along with error (stderr) output

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, pipe, output

There is a script run via cron with the following line:

```
0 * * * * (/var/script.sh | tee -a /var/script.log)
```

How do I rewrite the cron entry to capture both normal `stdout` and error `stderr` output? They are to be placed in different files.

Comment: @glennjackman Could you extend your comment to an answer, please. So it could also cover redirecting `stderr` output to the file.

Answer (score 2):

`cron` jobs are run by `sh` by default, and regardless of whether `sh` is a Bourne or POSIX `sh` or compatible, the syntax would be:

```
0 * * * * /var/script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/script.log
```

Where the `|` causes the two commands on either side to be run in parallel connected with a pipe with the stdout (fd 1) of the left one plugged to the writing end of the pipe and the stdin (fd 0) of the right one plugged to the reading end.

By adding `2>&1` to the left one, we have the fd 2 (stderr) point to the same resource as pointed out by fd 1: the writing end of the pipe, so both the normal and error output of `script.sh` will go to the pipe to `tee`.

`tee` will write it both to its stdout (which in the case of a cron job is either a pipe or temp file that will be used to send an email to the user) and to `script.log`.

That syntax also works in the `fish` shell.

With `(t)csh`, `zsh` or `bash` (4.0 or newer), you can also do:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh # or tcsh, bash ...
0 * * * * /var/script.sh |& tee -a /var/script.log
```

(where `SHELL=/bin/zsh` is how you tell `cron` to use a different shell to interpret the command lines).

In `fish`, you'd use `&|` instead of `|&`.

With `rc` (the once to be successor of `sh`) or derivatives, the syntax is:

```
SHELL=/bin/rc # or es, akanga
0 * * * * /var/script.sh >[2=1] | tee -a /var/script.log
```

With `zsh`, you can also do without `tee`  thanks to its `MULT_IOS` feature:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
0 * * * * /var/script.sh >&1 2>&2 >>& /var/script.log
```

Which would also have the benefit of preserving `script.sh`'s exit status, and also keeps `script.sh`'s stderr going to the original stderr in addition to `script.log` (though that doesn't make much of a difference in a cron job where stdout and stderr generally go to the same place anyway).

A few Bourne/POSIX like shells (`bash`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash`, `mksh` at least) have a `pipefail` option which you can use to be able to report errors in any component of a pipeline:

```
SHELL=/bin/ksh # or zsh, bash...
0 * * * * set -o pipefail && /var/script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /var/script.log
```

Comment: So many thanks for *that* much detail!

Answer (score 1):

cron wants to tell you about any cron job that produces output. It wants to email the results to you. If you don't want to receive email from cron, ensure your jobs produce no output: don't use `tee`, just redirect the output

```
0 * * * * /var/script.sh >> /var/script.log 2>&1
```

Note also I removed the parentheses: there's no point in running the script in a subshell.

Comment: D'oh!, Thank you @Stéphane as always!